# react-native-video inside flatlist showing black screen after scrolling some videos

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video

I am developing a flatlist with full screen videos like tiktok, it works fine for first 16/17 videos then when I scroll further it shows black screen.

Following is my code for the flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  style={{
    width: width,
    height: this.state.videoHeight,
  }}
  getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
    length: this.state.videoHeight,
    offset: this.state.videoHeight * index,
    index,
  })}
  onScrollToIndexFailed={(info) => {
    const wait = new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 500),
    );
    wait.then(() => {
      this.flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
        index: info.index,
        animated: false,
      });
    });
  }}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={this.state.allVideos}
  ref={this.flatlistRef}
  scrollEnabled={!this.state.isMinimizePlayer}
  viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
  decelerationRate={0}
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
  snapToAlignment={'start'}
  snapToInterval={this.state.videoHeight}
  horizontal={false}
  onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

Render function code

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <PlayerContext.Consumer>
    {({setVideo, setMetaData}) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          if (!this.state.isMinimizePlayer) {
            this.setState({isPause: !this.state.isPause});
          } else {
            this.maximizePlayr();
          }
        }}
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        style={{
          width: width,
          height: this.state.videoHeight,
        }}>
        <Video
          //  hideShutterView={false}
          // useTextureView={true}
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.playerRef[index] = ref;
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            width: this.state.videoWidth,
            height: this.state.videoHeight,
          }}
          resizeMode={'cover'}
          muted={this.state.isMute}
          paused={
            index == this.state.currentVisibleIndex
              ? this.state.isPause
              : true
            // index !== this.state.currentVisibleIndex ||
            // !this.state.isPause
          }
          onLoad={(data) => {
            // console.log('===>' + index);
          }}
          controls={false}
          hideShutterView={true}
          repeat={this.state.isLoop}
          onEnd={() => {
            if (!this.state.isLoop) {
              if (this.state.isAutoPlay) {
                if (
                  this.state.currentVisibleIndex <
                  this.state.allVideos.length - 1
                ) {
                  if (this.state.setGoNext) {
                    this.setState({setGoNext: false});
                    this._goToNextPage();
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      this.setState({setGoNext: true});
                    }, 1000);
                  }
                } else {
                  setVideo(null);
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          onProgress={(progress) => {
            if (this.state.currentTrackDuration == 0) {
              this.setState({
                currentTrackDuration: progress.seekableDuration,
              });
            }
            this.setState({
              progress: progress.currentTime / progress.seekableDuration,
            });
          }}
          bufferConfig={{
            minBufferMs: 15000,
            maxBufferMs: 50000,
            bufferForPlaybackMs: 1500,
            bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 1500,
          }}
          source={{uri: item.url}}
          poster={item.url}
          onError={(e) => console.log('video load failed!' + index, e)}
          onVideoError={(e) =>
            console.log('video error load failed!' + index, e)
          }
          onReadyForDisplay={() => {}}
          posterResizeMode={'cover'}></Video>
        {this.state.isMinimizePlayer && (
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: this.ThemedColors.happy,
              position: 'absolute',
              width: this.state.videoWidth,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              height: this.state.videoHeight,
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({isPause: !this.state.isPause});
              }}>
              <IconM
                name={!this.state.isPause ? 'play-arrow' : 'pause'}
                size={28}
                color={'white'}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
        {this.state.isMinimizePlayer && (
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              flex: 1,
              height: this.state.videoHeight,
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              left: 110,
              position: 'absolute',
              right: 10,
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}>
              <Text style={{}} numberOfLines={1}>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  marginTop: 5,
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  paddingLeft: 0,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../../../assets/Images/icon_eye.png')}
                  style={{
                    height: 10,
                    width: 16,
                    tintColor: 'black',
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={{marginLeft: 2}}>{this.metaData.from}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                setVideo(null);
              }}
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}>
              <Icon name="close" size={20} color={'black'} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}

        {!this.state.isMinimizePlayer && (
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['#000000', '#80000000']}
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0,
              paddingTop: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? width * 0.1 : width * 0.04,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
            }}>
            <Text style={this.ThemedStyles.videoTitleText} numberOfLines={1}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <View style={this.ThemedStyles.videoMomentContaine}>
              <Text style={this.ThemedStyles.videoDateText}>
                {moment.unix(item.createdAt / 1000).format('MMMM DD, YYYY')}
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={[
                  this.ThemedStyles.videoMomentText,
                  {backgroundColor: this.ThemedColors[item.moment]},
                ]}>
                {item.moment}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={this.ThemedStyles.videoMomentTagContaine}>
              {item?.tagN?.map((data) => {
                return (
                  <View>
                    <Text style={this.ThemedStyles.videoDateText}>
                      #{data}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </LinearGradient>
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  </PlayerContext.Consumer>
);
```

When scrolling it works and playing videos for first 16 videos then it show black screen for next videos and not playing them. When scrolling back to previous videos they are still playing but videos after 16th are black.